How to avoid save event auto trigger when we attach document to the doctype
When I am trying to attach files in doctype the form is getting automatically saved. I don’t need to save forms when I attach files. What to do with it?
When I attach file in my custom doctype, it triggers the save event automatically.
and i created a notification for job interview like when we click on save it sends notifications,
This leads to unwated notification sent, This is creating inconvenience. Please help.
i want to stop auto save after attaching a document.
Using Frappe Version 14

Frappe automatically triggers a save when file is attached which will trigger  the on_save event. To avoid this, you can technically block the form from auto-saving. See below code:
frappe.ui.form.on('SomeDocType', {
    before_save: function(frm) {
        if (frm.doc.__unsaved && frm.doc.file_attachment) {            
            return false;
        }
    }
});

However, this comes with potential issues for you.

Orphan Files: When  file is attached and not saved, the file gets uploaded but not linked to the document. This results in orphaned files on system if  user forget to save.
Audit logs on changes of forms won't be accurate.

Better Approach for you maybe:
Allow the form work as usual and improve when notifications are sent.how to achieve that:

Use a hidden field say skip_notification to track when a file is attached, and then conditionally suppress notifications if the save was triggered by a file attachment.

Client-Side Script to Track Attachment can be something like below:
frappe.ui.form.on('YSomeDocType', {
    file_attachment: function(frm) {       
        frm.set_value('skip_notification', true);
        frm.save_or_update(); 
    },
    after_save: function(frm) {       
        frm.set_value('skip_notification', false);
    }
});

If the notification on server side needs to be updated do that too. This way, you can solve the issue without creating new ones.

need to open the attach.js file and remove or comment these lines !!!!
this.frm.doc.docstatus == 1 ? this.frm.save("Update") : this.frm.save();

frappe/frappe/blob/version-15/frappe/public/js/frappe/form/controls/attach.js

